# Can I install a docker container using python?

Tags: python, docker

Does anyone know if I can pull and install a docker container from dockerhub using python? I was looking at the `docker-py` [documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), but I can't find anything about pulling images. The only references I saw were about using already installed images.

Note that most of the links I found while googling talk about installing pip inside of a docker container, but that is NOT what I want to do. That was just a caveat.

Now I was not sure if users needed `sudo` privileges to pull or start containers in docker. I want to create a command line tool that will pull down a docker container from dockerhub and start that image. Is there a way to do this in python, or does that need to be done through some sort of bash script?

Thanks.

Comment: You can pull an image: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.pull.

Comment: ... and [the github page](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) even says:"* ...It lets you **do anything the docker command does**, but from within Python apps ...*"

Comment: @Julia thanks for pointing out that command.

Comment: @Turing85 I see the reference there, but could not find the command. But Julia pointed it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull an image like this:

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
client.images.pull("hello-world")
output = client.containers.run("hello-world")

print(output.decode())
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the tip. I have not used the docker python library before, so just trying to understand where everything is in the library. Thanks.

Comment: The docs seem pretty great, and they're there for you to use :D